# Proguard: How to prevent the renaming of Packagename in Android?

Tags: java, android, proguard, obfuscation, mobile-development

I use a c++ native Library in my Android project, but when Proguard is Enabled, the app crashes. My code in c++ depends on the packagename, so I need to prevent the packagename from being renamed by Proguard. 
I used this rule so far, but it's not working:

```
  -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
  native <methods>;
  }
```

I appreciate you support.

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration to prevent specified package names from being obfuscated.

```
-keeppackagenames [package_filter]
```

A [filter](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#filters) is a list of comma-separated names that can contain wildcards.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this with no luck -keeppackagenames com.mycompany.myapp.** any suggestion please?